# Outlook 2010 - Login Scripts - auto configure non exchange account

Tags: group-policy, outlook, outlook-2010, login-script

I am looking for a way to configure MS Outlook 2010 with a login Script if possible so that when a new user logs into there PC it automatically sets outlook up so that there email account is there for them.

Please be aware we are NOT using Exchange, we are instead using a third party SMTP / Imap server.

I have done some research on this so far and it seems for Outlook 2003 you can create a PRF file provide the location of this file to outlook with a few command line parameters and it will do the rest. I have yet to find the utility to create these files for Office 2010.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate the creation of an outlook profile with PRF files:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062.aspx

http://www.outlook-tips.net/outlook-email-accounts/outlook-profile-file-prf/

Comment: ok that helped alot, just to clear this up the first link in the list relates to Outlook 2010, the second one relates to 2003.

On a seperate note, is there a way to store the account password inside these PRF files? as its going to be a pain if i cannot automate this totally.

Comment: A customer of ours used this the same way you intend it to use. AFAIK the users were set up completely, but they had to enter the password on the first login. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/password-pop3-account-created-prf-t2377797.html says it's not possible. Sue Mosher is absolutely an outlook expert. You could try a hack and manipulate the registry. OTOH, this does mention a password: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172073

Comment: To answer this question, there is presently no way provided by microsoft and the PRF creation system to store account passwords...